What were the territorial and political ambitions of Austria-Hungary towards Italy during World War I?
While there are many available explanations and descriptions regarding Italy's war aims against Austria-Hungary during World War I, I have been unable to find much information on Austria-Hungary's territorial and political ambitions towards Italy during that time period. If you could please provide me with some credible sources that outline Austria-Hungary's objectives and goals concerning Italy, I would greatly appreciate it.

Welcome to HistSE. Could you please tell us where you have looked already so that others don't duplicate your research. Thank you.

It should be noted that Austria-Hungary started the war having a loose alliance with Italy, and that keeping Italy out of the war was a goal pursued by Central Powers. Certainly, territorial ambitions of Austria-Hungary in Italy weren't a cause of the war, even if after the entry of Italy in the war some optimistic Austro-Hungarian might have come up with ideas for taking advantage of a victory over Italy.

The Austro-Hungarians had long-standing designs on Italian territory in Lombardy and Veneto.  Unfortunately for them their alliance with Germany meant the war kicked off with Italy "technically" an ally. Conrad von Hötzendorf (AH Field Marshall and Chief of the General Staff, basically the AH Supreme military commander) had a borderline-irrational Italian focus before the war and wanted to declare war on them when they refused to join the Central Powers (on the basis that their alliance only triggered if Germany/AH were not the aggressors).  Cooler heads prevailed and by the time the Italians entered the war on the allied side most central powers politicians/military commanders were more concerned about defending the border than claiming territory. Prit Buttar has a great series of books focused on the Eastern Front and lays out AH's situation before the war and during with great insight.

an anecdote on Conrad: during the 1908 messina heartquake, he suggested the emperor to attack italy, as the army was busy with the relief effort
